Rearrange and encode columns in pandas
i have data structured like this (working with pandas):
ID|comp_1_name|comp_1_percentage|comp_2_name|comp_2_percentage|
 1| name_1    | 13              | name_2    | 33              |
 2| name_3    | 15              | name_1    | 46              |

There are six comp_name/comp_percentage couple.
Names are not equally distributed in all six name columns.
I would like to obtain that kind of trasformation:
ID|name_1|name_2|name_3|
 1| 13   | 33   |  0   |      
 2| 46   | 0    |  15  |

I tried transposing (.T) both the entire dataframe and isolating the comp_name, comp_percentage couples, but to no avail.

Relevant user guide section: Reshaping and pivot tables

You can try using pd.wide_to_long with a little column renaming and shaping dataframe:
# Renaming columns to move name and percentage to the front for pd.wide_to_long
dfr = df.rename(columns=lambda x: '_'.join(x.rsplit('_', 1)[::-1]))

(pd.wide_to_long(dfr, ['name_', 'percentage_'], 'ID', 'No', suffix='.*')
  .reset_index()
  .pivot(index='ID', columns='name_', values='percentage_')
  .fillna(0)
  .reset_index()
  .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
  .astype(int))

Output:
   ID  name_1  name_2  name_3
0   1      13      33       0
1   2      46       0      15


I think i got the logic, but the .pivot part generate 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'. I'm sure that the 'ID' colums does not contains duplicate.

@AlessandroTogni this is because you have multiple values for intersecting index and column headers, instead of using .pivot, you will need to do some sort aggregation on these values, first, sum, mean... You will either need to use pivot_table with aggfunc or do a groupby and unstack to create your new table.

You can use a pivot table after reformating the dataframe to have only the 3 columns of interest:
df1 = df.iloc[:, 0:3]
df1. columns = ["ID", "name", "percentage"]
df2 = df.iloc[:, [0, 3, 4]]
df2. columns = df1.columns

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)
res =df.pivot(index="ID", columns="name", values="percentage").fillna(0)
display(res)


